# Не получается преобразовать массив определенным образом

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно преобразовать массив таким образом, чтобы сначала располагались все элементы, модуль которых не превышает `1`, а потом — все остальные.

Алгоритм понял,но в коде реализовать не получается,пробовал примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k = 0;
    cout << "n="; cin >> n;
    double* a = new double[n];

    cout << "Enter "<< n <<" elements:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (fabs(a[i]) <= 1)
        {
            for (int j = i; j > k; j--)
                swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
            k++;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    delete[]a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Типичная задача сортировки. Используйте функцию sort, функтор определите как: если модуль первого числа > 1 то false, иначе true. Вроде так должно сработать

Comment: А в чем конкретно ошибка? Не правильно выводит? Я например ввел 5 чисел `2.4 0.2 -1.5 -0.6 1` и получил вывод `0.2 -0.6 1 2.4 -1.5` вроде правильный вывод.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch как я понял автору не нужно сортировать, если я правильно понял.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков в вопросе: преобразовать массив таким образом, чтобы сначала располагались все элементы, модуль которых превышает 1, а потом все остальные - что это если не сортировка?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну сначала идут те которые по модулю < 1 а потом остальные :) не знаю как еще объяснить. Ну например `0.4 0.9 -0.6 5 -2 0.1` то вывод `0.4 0.9 -0.6 0.1 5 -2`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков и? Почему это не сортировка?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ааа точно, да вы правы, ну тогда я думаю автору лучше не функцию все таки использовать, точней преподавателю не понравится то что он использует функцию `sort`

Comment: Воспользуйтесь, например, функцией [`partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Или сами сделайте реализацию [algorithm partition](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0) со значением `pivot=1` (полная сортировка не требуется)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    double* a = new double[n];
    cout << "Enter " << n << " elements:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    cout << endl;
    partition(a, a + n, [](double b) {
        return fabs(b) <= 1;
        });

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    delete[]a;
    }
```

Comment: main.cpp:27:10: error: ‘partition’ was not declared in this scope
         });    Вот что он мне выдает

Comment: А вы что, не написали `#include <algorithm>`? Вот, смотрите - все работает: https://ideone.com/5m4e4s